# Does delete [] arr frees up the memory if called outside the function in which the arr was created in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management, delete-operator

Does delete [] arr frees up the memory if called outside the function in which the arr was created in C++?

I mean if I would have something like this

```
    double* f()
    {
    double* arr = new double[100];
    return arr;
    }

void ff()
{
double* arr = f();
delete [] arr;
}
```

Would be arr deleted properly in `ff()`?

Comment: It will. But consider using `std::vector` or smart pointers instead.

Comment: Yes, arr would be deleted. But this kind of memory management isn't good

Comment: Yes. As long as you don't lose track of the pointer.

Comment: And don't try and `delete` it twice.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ...... *and* smart pointers instead

Comment: So, does it mean that I can get the length of the array form pointer somehow, since the `delete []` is able to locate all the elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will be deleted properly (same with `delete`). As long as you keep track of the pointer, you can delete it outside the function the memory was allocated in.

Comment: same with `delete`? what do you mean?

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that `delete` would work the same way in this scenario (if OP had allocated with `new` instead of `new ...[]`), in case OP thought `delete[]` was a bit different here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  new (and new []) returns a pointer and that pointer is what you need to use on the corresponding delete (and delete []).